# how to calculate of sum of multiple conditional values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to get sums of conditional values and group by minute.

I succeeded with the following query but results takes some time and wonder is there any efficient way?

```
SELECT x.query, x.value, x.time FROM (
    SELECT id, query, SUM(VALUE) AS value, time FROM `modbuslogs` WHERE query IN ("sensor1","sensor2") AND time LIKE '2020-12-04%' GROUP BY HOUR(time), MINUTE(TIME) 
    UNION
    SELECT id, query, SUM(VALUE) AS value, time FROM `modbuslogs` WHERE query IN ("sensor3","sensor4") AND time LIKE '2020-12-04%' GROUP BY HOUR(time), MINUTE(TIME) 
) x
GROUP BY x.query, HOUR(time), MINUTE(TIME) 
ORDER BY x.id
```

Table structure:

```
+--------+-------+-----------------+
|  query | value |       time      |
+--------+-------+-----------------+
|sensor1 |   2   |2012-02-10 00:00 |
|sensor2 |   2   |2012-02-10 00:00 |
|sensor3 |   3   |2012-02-10 00:00 |
|sensor4 |   3   |2012-02-10 00:00 |
|sensor1 |   2   |2012-02-10 00:01 |
|sensor2 |   3   |2012-02-10 00:01 |
|sensor3 |   3   |2012-02-10 00:01 |
|sensor4 |   2   |2012-02-10 00:01 |
+--------+-------+-----------------+
```

Obtained and expected Output:

```
+--------+-------+-----------------+
|  query | value |       time      |
+--------+-------+-----------------+
|sensor1 |   4   |2012-02-10 00:00 |
|sensor3 |   6   |2012-02-10 00:00 |
|sensor1 |   5   |2012-02-10 00:01 |
|sensor3 |   5   |2012-02-10 00:01 |
+--------+-------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point for the `union` subquery in the first place. This is equivalent to your query:

```
select id, query, sum(value) as value, min(time) as time
from modbuslogs
where 
    query in ('sensor1', 'sensor2', 'sensor3', 'sensor4')
    and time >= '2020-12-04'
    and time <  '2020-12-05'
group by query, hour(time), minute(time)
```

This gives one row per `query` and per minute, with the sum of `value`. Not that we need an aggregate function around `time`, so the `select` clause is consistent with the `group by` clause. Also, the `where` clause uses date filtering rather than string matching.

On the other hand, if you want the two groups of sensors in two different columns, then use conditional aggrgation:

```
select id, min(time) as time,
    sum(case when query in ('sensor1', 'sensor2') then value else 0 end) as value_1_2, 
    sum(case when query in ('sensor3', 'sensor4') then value else 0 end) as value_3_4
from modbuslogs
where 
    query in ('sensor1', 'sensor2', 'sensor3', 'sensor4')
    and time >= '2020-12-04'
    and time <  '2020-12-05'
group by hour(time), minute(time)
```

Comment: I used your second query. Excelent. Thank you so much